# How to use 'by' and 'of'

Tags: british-english, possessives

How to use possessive *by* and *of* ? On the internet I have read that we use **by** with one work or one kind of work and **of** when we mean all the works.

- Example: A writer A wrote many books. He wrote five *romantic books* and eight *adventure books*.

  1. This romantic book is **by** **A**.
  2. All the books are **of A**.
- Example: A writer B wrote eleven books (five horror books, six school books), built five houses, painted seven paintings and make three cars.

  1. These three horror books are **by B**.
  2. All these books (eleven) are **by B**.
  3. These two paintings and those two houses are **by B**.
  4. These paintings (seven) and houses (five) are **by B**.
  5. All these things (eleven books, five houses, seven paintings, three cars) are **of B**.

Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: Is this the thing you're referring to?  ["When you are talking about everything someone has painted, written, etc., use of. When you are referring to one or more examples of someone's work, use by: a painting *by* Monet"](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/of)  It's OK advice, but we don't usually say "the books **are of A**", we would say "the books **are by A**" or "the books **of A**".  For some reason it sounds strange and nonstandard to say "are of A".

Comment: @stangdon Yes, I meant the article.

Comment: @stangdon It means we can say _Paintings and cars are by Johanes._  and _Paintings and cars of Johanes._. Does it means we use **be + by** and **noun + of** ?

Comment: Yes - I don't know if it's a *rule* exactly, but it sounds more natural to me to say **be + by** and **noun + of**, as you say.

Answer (score 1):

Books are written BY people, drawings/paintings made BY them, houses built BY them.

The preposition BY is being used to introduce the agent.

The preposition OF is used in these cases for content.

> > A book OF love stories, a painting OF my son, a house (made) OF wood.

The preposition OF can also be used possessively to indicate to whom something belongs.

> > A book of John's, the house of the parson.

It is also possible to refer to:

> > A poem/play of Shakespeare's

meaning a poem that he composed; that's to say, by Shakespeare.

It's a bit trickier when it comes to a painting/drawing of:

> > A painting/drawing of John

means that an artist has painted or drawn a portrait of John.

> > A painting/drawing of John's

means that it belongs to John.

Comment: I mean this : _When you are talking about everything someone has painted, written, etc., use of. When you are referring to one or more examples of somebody’s work, use by:a painting by Monet_

Comment: @ĽubomírMasarovič This distinction is only observed in attributive use  (*Hamlet **by** Shakespeare*, *the plays **of** Shakespeare*); in predicative use only *by* is used (*All these plays **are by** Shakespeare*).

Comment: @StoneyB Does it mean we use **be + by** and **noun + of** ?